# Error while trying to read a csv using pandas.

Tags: python, pandas

My xor.csv is:

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,y
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1
0,0,1,0,1
0,0,1,1,0
0,1,0,0,1
0,1,0,1,0
0,1,1,0,0
0,1,1,1,1
```

Code to fetch this file using pandas is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

testing_data = pd.read_csv('..\Data_Set\xor.csv')
```

And it gives me this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\harmee\Desktop\python_tut\ML\NN\toy_nn.py", line 11
     testing_data = pd.read_csv('..\Data_Set\xor.csv')
                          ^
  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 11-12: truncated \xXX escape
```

Tried using the encoding attribute using `encoding = 'utf-8'` and `encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'` but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Try reading the data by passing raw string pd.read_csv(r'..\Data_Set\xor.csv')

Comment: The duplicate explains the issue really well

Answer (score 1):

Pass dataset path as either by single forward slash(/) or by double backward slash(\\).

Try this:

testing_data = pd.read_csv('../Data_Set/xor.csv')

or

testing_data = pd.read_csv('..\\Data_Set\\xor.csv')

or

testing_data = pd.read_csv(r'..\Data_Set\xor.csv')

Both will work the same.

Comment: Tried the forward slash (/), didn't work.

Comment: Try putting (r'..\Data_Set\xor.csv')

Comment: That works, thanks!